# downplay, play down; downscale, scale down

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs, connotations

There are quite a few words that are formed with down/ up either preceding the actual rootword, or as a particle making for a phrasal verb. But does it change the meaning in any way or carry different connotations?
Play down - downplay
Scale down- downscale

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, my suggestion is always to check a good dictionary first, there may be differences in usages and/or meaning, case by case:

In the example you make:

play down and  donwplay have similar meaning and usages:

> - If you [play down something](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/play-down), you try to make people believe that it is not particularly important.
> - If you [downplay](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/downplay) a factor or  feature, you try to make people think that it is less important or serious than it really is.

as in the case of scale down or downscale:

> If you [scale down something](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scale-down), you make it smaller in size, amount, or extent than it used to be.
>
> - One factory has had to scale down its workforce from six hundred to only six.
>
> [to donwscale](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/downscale):  reduce (something) in size, amount, extent, cost, etc.; downsize
>
> - We want to downscale and buy a smaller house.

(Collins Dictionary)